# Como exibir número decimais - iReport

Tags: variáveis, ireport

Estou com uma dificuldade inesperada para exibir os números decimais no iReports, por exemplo se a minha variável possui a seguinte conta 180 / 180 ela me exibe corretamente 1 porém se é 162/180 ele me exibe apenas 0 ao invés de 0.9, minha variável é no formato Float no iReport,  é necessário alguma configuração a mais para que ela exiba as casas decimais?

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="523" y="0" width="32" height="20" uuid="9fc5b15c-8007-478e-aef2-edebe1603ab1"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{centoOitenta} / 180]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o jfxml do campo com problemas?

Comment: @GustavoFragoso alterei a pergunta seria isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que você notou aconteceu porque ocorreu um cast para int ao colocar apenas **180**, ao invés de **180.0**. Tenha sempre em mente que embora o JasperReports seja um pouco confuso ele é escrito em Java por isso soluções para um código comum tem grandes changes de funcionar também em um Field Expression por exemplo.

Para ajeitar o número de casas decimais ai teremos que usar uma classe que nos proporcione esses recursos, vou usar aqui o [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Coloque isso no seu Field Expression:

```
// Field agora é do tipo string
new BigDecimal($F{field}).divide(new BigDecimal("180.0"), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

[Alguns sites](http://blog.caelum.com.br/arredondamento-no-java-do-double-ao-bigdecimal/) recomendam que se use uma string no construtor para evitar um erro de conversão mas não tenho certeza se isso ainda é válido. Quando à questão do **infinity** eu não sei. Pense em como você exibiria da maneira que deseja em um código Java comum.

Comment: Perfeito, deu certo, uma pergunta eu consigo configurar para exibir apenas no máximo duas casas decimais?

Comment: Fui testar em todos os dados do relatório e algumas linhas onde a conta é 1/(0/180.0) ele esta trazendo a palavra `infinity` tu saberia como resolver isso?

Comment: Eu tentei fazer uma divisão assim: `new BigDecimal($F{quantidade}).divide(new BigDecimal($F{centoOitenta}).divide(new BigDecimal("180.0"), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))` onde eu quero que o conteudo `$F{quantidade}` seja dividido pelo resultado ad divisão de `new BigDecimal($F{centoOitenta}).divide(new BigDecimal("180.0"), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`. Isso é possível?

Comment: Coloca esse código num programa Java de teste dentro de um println com alguns valores aleatórios.

Comment: Consegui definindo um `pattern` pro resultado da conta, obrigado pela ajuda :)